# C program compilation in many directories with a delay

Tags: c, linux, bash, compilation

I have directories named 0001_1000_solar, 0002_1000_solar, ... 1000_1000_solar. I want to go to each directory, compile a C program, pause for a second and move to another directory and do the same thing.

I wrote something like that in my terminal but it does not work:

> for num in {0001..1000}; do
>
> ```
>    cd $num_1000_solar
>    gcc singl.c binary.c -lm
>    sleep 1
>    cd ..
> ```
>
> done

It takes me from the current directory to my user directory... Any ideas?

Cheers.

> 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `$num_1000_solar` is the problem. Only $num has the assigned value.

It should be `cd {$num}_1000_solar`

In the current case $num_1000_solar is an undefined variable, so it is empty. Hence the command becomes just `cd` , which takes you to your home directory.

**Edit**

Answer updated.
 Thanks to the suggestions from redimp and Klas.

Comment: I would suggest to use  `cd ${num}_1000_solar`.

Comment: I often use `{}` around the variable name: `cd ${num}_1000_solar`. I find that syntax more readable, but that's my personal preference.